# How to combine all predicates from List<Predicate<MyClass>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, predicate

I have one problem and I'm sure you help me with my wrinkle.

I have

```
List<Predicate<TaskFx>> predicates
```

and I want to use these predicates in

```
taskFxList.stream().filter(predicates).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

as a one predicate merged like:

```
predicate1.and(predicate2).and...
```

I have a table (13 columns) with some results (in JavaFx) and 6 fields to search in this table by the values from these fields. I can enter for example values only to 3 fields so my

```
predicates.size() = 3;
```

The question is how best to prepare dynamically one

```
Predicate<TaskFx> predicate
```

consisting all predicates merged by x.and(y).and(z)

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can stream and [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) them like this:

```
Predicate<TaskFx> predicate = predicates.stream()
        .reduce(x -> true, Predicate::and);
```

Comment: I prefer `.reduce(Predicate::and).orElse(x -> true);` as it avoids an obsolete combining of an always `true` predicate with an existing predicate.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you could just process them like this:

```
List<TaskFx> resultSet = stringList.stream()
                                   .filter(e -> predicates.stream().allMatch(x -> x.test(e)))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```