# Using a list of functional interfaces in java stream filter

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list of objects which needs to be filtered with another list of functional interfaces.

For example:

```
List<SomeClass> originalList = .....
List<SomeClass> filteredList = originalList.stream().filter(filterList).toList();
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How do I use a list of functional interfaces here such that
the final list contains objects filtered by all the filters in the list. Where

```
List<FilterClass> filterList = Arrays.asList(
    new ClassWhichImplementsFilterClass1(),
    new ClassWhichImplementsFilterClass2()
);
```

FilterClass.java

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface FilterClass{
    boolean isValid(SomeClass someClass);
}
```

How do I achieve this? I think I can do this by streaming the list of objects and then passing that object through each filter class in the `filterList`, but is there a way to do it some other way.

Comment: [Stream.filter()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) uses a [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) as argument. Why are you trying to use it your own functional interface for argument, it won't even compile?

Comment: As mentioned in the other [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74489011/using-a-list-of-functional-interfaces-in-java-stream-filter#comment131492938_74489011), method `filter` takes a single `Predicate` parameter and not a `List` of `Predicate`. Can you post a concrete example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: filter can take a Predicate but the predicate itself can be a stream. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553761/how-to-apply-multiple-predicates-to-a-java-util-stream.

Comment: Possible duplicate - [How to combine all predicates from List<Predicate<MyClass>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47424197/how-to-combine-all-predicates-from-listpredicatemyclass).

Comment: The only way i see this whole thing working out, is if you wrap your `FilterClass` inside a `Predicate`, but why bother? `Predicate` provides literary the same functionality, and some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 separate issues here; I shall cover them both.

### FilterClass probably shouldn't exist

The name is very strange (it's an interface; things that implement it generally are barely considered a class, the only interpretation that lets you state that they are, means *everything* is, and thus the presence of `Class` in the name of the thing doesn't add any information). It's also pointless to make this interface; java already has it: `Predicate<SomeClass>`:

```
class Student {
  @Getter public LocalDate birthDate;
}

Predicate<Student> isAdult = s -> ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(
  LocalDate.now(), s.getBirthDate()) >= 18;
```

### Applying multiple filters

Evidently, you have a list of filters. How would you like to apply this multitude? There are 4 obvious answers:

- If ALL filters match the item, it passes, otherwise, remove it from the stream.
- If just ONE filter matches the item, it passes, otherwise, remove it from the stream.
- If ALL filters match the item, it *fails and is removed*, otherwise, pass the item.
- If just ONE filter matches the item, it *fails and is removed*. The item survives only if all filters fail to match it.

Regardless of your choice, you just.. program it. Write a new predicate that implements your choice. For example, if you want the top choice:

```
List<Predicate<Student>> filterList = ...;
Predicate<Student> allMatch = s -> {
  for (var pred : filterList) if (!pred.test(s)) return false;
  return true;
}

foo.stream().filter(allMatch).collect(....);
```

You may instead use the various utility methods in `Predicate` itself to construct a new predicate. For example, the above can alternatively be implemented using predicate's own `and` method:

```
List<Predicate<Student>> filterList = ...;
Predicate<Student> allMatch = s -> true;
for (var pred : filterList) allMatch = allMatch.and(pred);
```

Or even:

```
List<Predicate<Student>> filterList = ...;
Predicate<Student> allMatch = filterList.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.reducing(s -> true, Predicate::and));
```

NB: If you insist on keeping your own `FilterClass` interface for this exercise, pretty much only the first option would be available to you, unless you fully duplicate all of `java.util.function.Predicate` and also add the default `and` method just like Predicate has.

Comment: Please ignore the class names as it is only for this example.

Comment: Yes I can change it to a predicate. But my requirement is that I want the filter/predicate to follow the interface signature. So I define the method signature, its input for the predicate and I want people to extend this to write other filters.

Comment: The second of the four snippets is your answer then.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues you need to consider:

- Stream-operations like `filter` expect a `Predicate` (i.e. it's not possible to pass into `filter` anything that is not of type `Predicate`).
- You can't use your instance of your custom interface as a `Predicate` unless it doesn't extend a `Predicate`.
- A *Functional interface* (that's the only purpose of this annotation), i.e. it has only one `abstract` method. If your instance extends `Predicate` it would inherit `abstract` method test, i.e. it can't declare it own `abstract` method. You can preserve `isValid()` as a default method.

If you want to leave your interface as is then you can perform validation like this:

```
List<Filter> filters = List.of();
    
List<SomeClass> originalList = List.of();
        
List<SomeClass> filteredList = originalList.stream()
    .filter(foo -> filters.stream().anyMatch(filter -> filter.isValid(foo))) // or `.allMatch` depending of how validation should be performed
    .toList(); // for Java 16+ or collect(Collectors.toList())
```

And if you extend `Predicate` your interface might look like this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Filter extends Predicate<SomeClass> {
    
    default boolean isValid(SomeClass someClass) {
        return test(someClass);
    }
}
```

Then you would be able to make use of the default methods `Predicate.and()` / `Predicate.or()` and chain your custom predicates:

```
List<Filter> filters = List.of();
        
Predicate<SomeClass> allMatch = filters.stream().map(Predicate.class::cast).reduce(t -> true, Predicate::and);
Predicate<SomeClass> anyMatch = filters.stream().map(Predicate.class::cast).reduce(t -> false, Predicate::or);

List<SomeClass> originalList = List.of();
        
List<SomeClass> filteredList = originalList.stream()
    .filter(anyMatch)
    .toList(); // for Java 16+ or collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: Yes, I will use a Predicate. Sorry about using a FunctionalInterface. But is there a way to make sure filters extend my Predicate Interface so that it conforms to my input params ? Basically I would want people to add more filters that extend my base Predicate interface and then all these filters will get applied to the list of objects.

Comment: I would like a list to hold the implemented predicates and people just add their predicate to the list.

Comment: @v1shnu If you declare your interface `Filter` as extending `Predicate`, then **automatically** any interface that extends `Filter` would be also of type `Predicate`. And anyone would be able to extend it, unless it's marked as `sealed`. If that's not what you were asking for, please rephrase the question.